# What does "inne hält" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, style, grammaticality

> Granatapfel ist eine seit jahrtausenden verwendete Frucht, welche wegen ihrer wohltuenden Wirkstoffe den Beinamen "Frucht der Könige" **inne hält**.

In dict.cc I have only found *innehalten* (written together), and it means *to stop* or *to pause* what doesn't seem to fit the context.

Comment: I think it should be one word and it's supposed to basically mean "hat". IMHO using "innehalten" is not only out of place because its common meaning is "to stop" but also because just using less common words doesn't automatically make a text more colorful. It often only makes it more pretentious. I think "tragen" would be the best choice.

Comment: Yes, but the word would be _innehaben_, i.e. inne hat (not: hält). It's a mistake in the original text in my opinion.

Comment: @Ingmar.. if it's innehaben, shouldn't it be innehat?

Comment: Yes. ... eine Frucht, die den Beinamen ... innehat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your were right. **innehalten** means to stop for a moment. Additionaly ther's a missing article at the beginning.

Your text should read:

> **Der** Granatapfel ist eine seit jahrtausenden verwendete Frucht, welche wegen ihrer wohltuenden Wirkstoffe den Beinamen "Frucht der Könige" **inne hat**.

Comment: Kann man wirklich einen Namen ***inne*** haben? Das kommt mir seltsam vor.

Comment: Warum nicht? Das wäre dann jedenfalls eine bloße Frage des Stils; gramamtikalische ist daran nichts auszusetzen.

Comment: @Takkat - Im Moment konnte ich keine Beispiele finden, aber immerhin hat man einen Namen, man hält ihn nicht. Ausserdem würde ich dem Begriff innehalten einen gewissen Bezug zu anhalten zuschreiben.

Comment: So many mistakes in a product description... And this text is not only on [the company's website](http://www.clubmate.de/club-mate-granat.html), but on the product itself as well.

Comment: @user11181 - Thats the result when browers try to be trendy writers.